# Como subtrair dois objetos datetime.time em Python

Tags: python, django, datetime, framework

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site com django e em um dos campos eu preciso fazer a subtração de dois campos datetime porém já vi um monte de erros, tentei transformar o models em **charfield** junto com os forms porém vi vários erros como

> strptime() argument 2 must be str, not datetime.time
>
> descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

mesmo depois de tentar fazer um monte de coisa eu não achei a solução. Depois de muito tempo pesquisando eu achei um site falando sobre como fazer a subtração de dois datetime.

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz tudo: "*strptime() argument 2 must be str, not datetime.time*" - em algum lugar (que não temos como saber porque vc não colocou nenhum código) está chamando `strptime`, e no segundo argumento está sendo passando um objeto que é um `datetime.time` (sendo que deveria ser uma string).

Answer (score 0):

**Eu não sei se essa é a melhor solução, mas é a que eu achei depois de muito tempo procurando**

Para resolver o problema do datetime, eu acabei voltando os models pra datetime denovo, os relacionados ao problema ficaram assim

```
entrada_manha = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
saida_manha = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
entrada_tarde = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
saida_tarde = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

> depois de voltar o forms pro timefield eu criei uma nova pasta chamada templatetags, adicionei os arquivos  ****init**.py** e o **custom_tags.py**  no mesmo nível dos templates e no html que eu queria os dados eu coloquei

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

> na parte que eu joguei as variáveis para a função dentro do arquivo custom tags eu usei:

```
{% for atividade in atividades %}
            <td>{{ atividade.entrada_manha }}</td>
            <td>{{ atividade.saida_manha }}</td>
            <td>{{ atividade.entrada_tarde }}</td>
            <td>{{ atividade.saida_tarde }}</td>
            <td>{% tempo_total atividade.entrada_manha atividade.saida_manha atividade.entrada_tarde atividade.saida_tarde %} </td>
```

> e dentro do arquivo **custom_tags.py** eu criei a fórmula

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tempo_total(entrada_m,saida_m,entrada_t,saida_t):
    horario_base = "00:00:00"
    base_subtracao= datetime.datetime.strptime(horario_base,"%H:%M:%S")
    time1= datetime.datetime.combine(base_subtracao,entrada_m)
    time2= datetime.datetime.combine(base_subtracao,saida_m)
    time3= datetime.datetime.combine(base_subtracao,entrada_t)
    time4= datetime.datetime.combine(base_subtracao,saida_t)
    resultado= (time2-time1)+(time4-time3)
    return resultado
```